# Javascript -DOM-calculator display digits on a screen

Tags: javascript, function, dom

Im implementing a calculator, and I'm stuck trying to display the digit on the screen. I iterate trough all my digit to get them, but when I try to replace them in order to display them in my div with the id #nums it won't work. this is the function i'm stuck with

```
   buttons.forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   console.log('it work') 
   document.querySelector('#nums').textContent = buttons.innerHTML
     })
  })
```

here is a fiddle to see more

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

function substract(a, b) {
  return a - b
}

function sum(arr) {
  result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result += arr[i]
  }
  return result
}
/*
function multiply_range(arr){
 result = 1;
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  result *= arr[i]
 }
 return result
}
*/

function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b
}

function divide(a, b) {
  return a / b
}


var sum = document.getElementById('sum');
var substract = document.getElementById('minus')
var multiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
var divide = document.getElementById('divide')




function operate(operator, a, b) {
  if (operator === sum) {
    return add(a, b);

  } else if (operator === substract) {
    return substract(a, b);
  } else if (operator === multiply) {
    return multiply(a, b);
  } else if (operator === divide) {
    return divide(a, b);
  }
}

operate(sum, 1, 1);


var display_value = document.querySelector('#nums');

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.number-btn')

// loop through all the buttons 
// Object.keys(buttons) transform my object in a array
/*
Object.keys(buttons).forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('it work') 
   })
})
*/
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('it work')
    document.querySelector('#nums').textContent = buttons.innerHTML
  })
})

/*
var btn_1 = document.querySelector('#btn-1')

btn_1.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log('it work')
 document.querySelector('#nums').textContent  = btn_1.textContent
})

*/
/*
document.querySelector('#nums').textContent = 0;
*/
/*
document.getElementsByClassName('number-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
 
 display_value == document.queryselector('nums'); 
})
*/
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 85%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #cc1515;
}

#btn-equals {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.number-btn {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.operator-btn {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.results {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

.contour {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#nums {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}

#operator {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contour">
    <p>The calculator</p>
    <div id="results" class="results">
      <div id="nums">55</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button id="sum" class="operator-btn">+</button>
      <button id="minus" class="operator-btn">-</button>
      <button id="multiply" class="operator-btn">x</button>
      <button id="divide" class="operator-btn">/</button>
      <button id="btn-7" class="number-btn">7</button>
      <button id="btn-8" class="number-btn">8</button>
      <button id="btn-9" class="number-btn">9</button>
      <button id="btn-4" class="number-btn">4</button>
      <button id="btn-5" class="number-btn">5</button>
      <button id="btn-6" class="number-btn">6</button>
      <button id="btn-1" class="number-btn">1</button>
      <button id="btn-2" class="number-btn">2</button>
      <button id="btn-3" class="number-btn">3</button>
      <button id="btn-period" class="number-btn">.</button>
      <button id="btn-O" class="number-btn">0</button>
      <button id="btn-clear" class="number-btn">AC</button>
      <button id="btn-equals" class="operator-btn">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `button.innerHTML` not `buttons.innerHTML`

The array is called `buttons` - each item you're pulling out is being initialized as `button`. You want to set the div equal to that *item's* innerHTML, not the array `buttons` - which, as it is an array to begin with,  does not have an `innerHTML` property. Furthermore, it wasn't clear in your question, but if you would like to keep adding digits to the calculator box, be sure to use the `+=` operator instead of the `=`, like so `document.querySelector('#nums').textContent += button.innerHTML` That way it will keep adding to each box on button press.

If you would like the buttons to just replace the previous item in the calculator window, this will work:

```
buttons.forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.querySelector('#nums').textContent = button.innerHTML
     })
  })
```

**EDIT:** As a matter of fact, since you just want the text node within your HTML, it would be better for performance to simply use `button.textContent` or as @Barmar pointed out, `this.textContent` ( `this` also references `button` )

`textContent` is faster because when you utilize `innerHTML` the Browser Engine has to reprocess and parse everything while it copies it over. `textContent` specifically only deals with a text node and the content therein.

```
buttons.forEach(button => {
 button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 document.querySelector('#nums').textContent = button.textContent;
 })
})
```

Comment: You can also use `this.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be button and not buttons :)

`document.querySelector('#nums').textContent = button.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('#nums').textContent += button.innerHTML;